# How to draw polygons in QGIS perfectly aligned

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation, alignment

I would like to draw polygons for an indoor map test and would like to draw perfect rectangles (horiz. and  vertical edges). 
How to set QGIS options on polygon edit /draw to do that?

Answer (score 4):

There is a [CadTools Plugin](http://www.catais.org/qgis/cadtools/). AFIK it is only suitable tool for this task at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Hope that I got your question right..The plugin "rectangles ovals digitizig tools" lets you draw perfect polygons.
Just set the vector layer on edit and and draw them.